# Logstash /usr/local/etc/logstash/conf.d/ folder does not exist after installation

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, logstash, homebrew, elastic-stack

After installing logstash via Homebrew I attempted to set a new `.conf` file under the following path:

```
/usr/local/etc/logstash/conf.d/
```

Strangely, the `conf.d` folder doesnt seem to exist.

Im using `logstash version 6.7.0`

To install all I did was use the homebrew command:

```
brew install logstash
```

Any reason why it wasnt created?

Comment: did you follow all(https://logz.io/blog/elk-mac/) these steps?

Comment: @Avi yes, thats the exact guide I used :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not create the `conf.d` directory, the `conf.d` directory is created by the packaged versions, `.deb` or `.rpm`, the homebrew formula for logstash uses the `.tar.gz` version where the config files are in the `config` directory.

Looking the [code](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/logstash.rb) for the logstash formula you can see that in the post-install it just creates a symbolic link to the `config` directory.

```
def post_install
    ln_s etc/"logstash", libexec/"config"
  end
```

You will need to create the directory by yourself if you do not want to save your `.conf` files in the `/usr/local/etc/logstash/`.

Comment: Thanks Leandro, that makes sense.